# Debugger in PyCharm doesn't run

Tags: python-3.x, debugging, pycharm

When I start my project and tap Shift+F10, PyCharm open console with "/usr/bin/python3.7". Code doesn't running, even if I reboot Linux.

I changed interpreter to System, then on Virtual but it doesn't change anything

Comment: https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/6/17/e0d7345b960785087a9dd02bb7fee288-full.png

Comment: @cssyphus I made the switch from VSCode to PyCharm, because VSCode doesn't have so many functionality as PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have switch some options in "Debug Configuration"
Exactly I edit script path to the main.py

On picture I emphasize by mouse, what I exactly changed

https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/6/17/ab0f2c97212b8315b39b46eece86c1db-full.png